# What is the price when the buy limit is above sell limit

Tags: limit-order-book

Consider a marketplace where the sell order book has one order for 10 units at 1\$, then 10 units at 1.1\$ and then 100 units at 2\$. Say that I want to buy 20 units, and that I place a limit order for 20 units at 1.1\$. What then, would the price be when the first order is settled? The seller is only demanding 1\$ but I offer 1.1\$.

How about the reverse case? Say the buy order book has one order for 10 units at 1.1\$, then 10 units at 1\$ and then 100 units at 0.5\$. If I place a sell order for 20 units at 1\$, at what price will the first order execute? I only ask for 1\$ but the buyer is offering 1.1\$.

Comment: If you make a purchase order of 20 units, you will have the 10 units at 1 and the 10 units at 1.1.

Comment: @Wiles01 How about the reverse case? (I'll put this in the question also). Say the buy order book has one order for 10 units at 1.1\$, then 10 units at 1\$ and then 100 units at 0.5\$. If I place a sell order for 20 units at 1\$, at what price will the first order execute? I only ask for 1\$ but the buyer is offering 1.1\$.

Comment: Good for you then if the buyer is offering more! Then, you will have the first 10 at 1.1 and the other 10 at 1. Have a look also at this nice post: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/how-do-buy-and-sell-orders-work

Comment: @Wiles01 Thanks for the link! So the rule seems to be that orders are always executed in favor of the most recent order. Is this a universal rule in all marketplaces? The provided link refers to bitcoin exchanges.

Comment: I cannot guarantee that the "best execution" is always the take but this is the case for the big marketplaces. You can also have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_execution

Comment: It's not the most recent, it's the best price.

Comment: @Wiles01 Thanks for the link!

Comment: @LazyCat Best price for whom? If I place my buy limit at 1.1\$, it's of course great for me if I can scoop up 10 units from the seller who put a sell limit at 1\$. However, for that seller, it would be better to execute the order at 1.1\$, which is still within my buy limit. It then seems that the more recent order has priority in deciding at which end of the price range the order is settled.

Comment: Most aggressive price. So the highest for buy orders, the lowest price for sell orders that are in the book.

Comment: @LazyCat Ok, I see. Thanks!